# postgresql error group by and aggregate error

Tags: postgresql, odbc

I have a code to use for my table to count number of download by flight date  and register number for each day . It gives this error

```
SELECT  "public".aircraft.aircraft_id, COUNT(*) AS TOTALDOWNLOAD, "public".aircraft.register_number, to_char("public".flight.flight_date, 'DDMMYYYY') as flight_date , to_char("public".flight.health_start_date, 'hh24:mi') as health_start_date, to_char("public".flight.health_end_date, 'hh24:mi') as health_end_date,  "public".flight.maintenance_flight_time 
FROM  "public".flight  

INNER JOIN   "public".aircraft
ON
"public".flight.aircraft_id = "public".aircraft.id
WHERE "public".flight.maintenance_flight_time > 0 
Group by "public".flight.flight_date, "public".aircraft.register_number
```

error details below :

```
ERROR [42803] ERROR: column "aircraft.aircraft_id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function;
Error while executing the query (PSQLODBC35W.DLL)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GROUP BY`s are kind of tricky. Since you're only interested in the COUNT, I'd pare down the query to get rid of all of the parameters you aren't going to use. And if you think about it, if you're grouping by flight_date, what is the DB supposed to return for some of the other fields -- such as health_start_date? It doesn't know what to do, so it throws an error.

Start with this cut down version. I'm not sure if the WHERE clause will cause trouble or not. You may have to GROUP BY flight_date alias instead of "public".flight.flight_date. And you'll definitely have to GROUP BY the alias if `"public".flight.flight_date` is a timestamp. Depending on how big these tables are, it might be slow to do the to_char conversion. Using `date("public".flight.flight_date` might be faster.

```
SELECT to_char("public".flight.flight_date, 'DDMMYY') as "flight date",
       COUNT(*) AS TOTALDOWNLOAD, "public".aircraft.register_number
FROM  "public".flight  
INNER JOIN  "public".aircraft ON
            "public".flight.aircraft_id = "public".aircraft.id
WHERE "public".flight.maintenance_flight_time > 0 
GROUP BY "flight date", "public".aircraft.register_number
ORDER BY "flight date"
```

Comment: Thanks. It does gives an output but the count is 1 for everything !

Comment: @great77. First try to `GROUP BY` alias `flight_date` instead of `"public".flight.flight_date`. If that doesn't work,try to do some debugging. Try to temporarily change `GROUP BY` to `ORDER BY` and remove `COUNT(*) AS TOTALDOWNLOAD,` to see how many records you get. If there is only one record per date in the data, that would explain results.

Comment: I debugged it now and and have the same number of records each date per record

Comment: @great77. Dude, you gotta help me help you. How many records per date? What did you change? What happens when you `GROUP BY` flight_date alias? I just had another idea. Change `flight_date` alias to something else (e.g. "flight_date2") to be sure that postgres is using the alias then `GROUP BY` the new alias.

Comment: I figured it out now. I need to group by to_char("public".flight.flight_date, 'DDMMYYYY'), "public".aircraft.register_number  and then order by order by   to_char("public".flight.flight_date, 'DDMMYYYY')   . It is now working . Thanks. I will accept your answer.

Comment: @great77. One more thing. This will make your query a little more readable. Can you change your alias from `flight_date` to `"flight date"` (don't forget quotes)? You can use `"flight date"` in your `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` clauses and makes it (in my view, anyway) easier to read.